# spring.io download jar Received status code 401 from server

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Today when I refresh the java project which was using gradle as the build tool, shows error:

```
Could not download spring-native-0.10.0.jar (org.springframework.experimental:spring-native:0.10.0)
Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/experimental/spring-native/0.10.0/spring-native-0.10.0.jar'.
Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/experimental/spring-native/0.10.0/spring-native-0.10.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server:

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to avoid this issue? It seems to need login to download the jar. BTW, I did not import the `org.springframework.experimental:spring-native:0.10.0` in anywhere of my project. This is the project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/common.gradle"

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.11.RELEASE"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.arenagod.gradle:mybatis-generator-plugin:1.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.7"
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.4.3"
    id 'com.github.ayltai.spring-graalvm-native-plugin' version '1.4.10'
    id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.3.4"

}

apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/common.gradle"

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin'


    configurations.all {
        // exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        // exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-core"
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-simple"
        /** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484542/redis-command-timed-out-nested-exception-is-io-lettuce-core-rediscommandtimeout
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244405/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unable-to-find-gatewayfilterfactory-with-nam
         * the spring gateway project needs to using lettuce
         * because the jedis did not support reactive until 2022.08
         * only lettuce support reactive
         * so we should not exclude the lettuce for the whole project
        **/
        // exclude group: "io.lettuce", module: "lettuce-core"
        /**
         * why exclude the gson?
         * https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1826
         */
        // exclude group: "com.google.code.gson", module: "gson"

        // check for updates every build
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

        // check for updates every build
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.jsqlparser') {
                    details.useVersion "2.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients' && details.requested.name == 'jedis' ) {
                    details.useVersion("3.8.0")
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework.data' && details.requested.name == 'spring-data-redis' ) {
                    details.useVersion("2.7.2")
                }
                //exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-redis"
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.postgresql' && details.requested.name == 'postgresql' ) {
                    details.useVersion("42.2.23")
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j' && details.requested.name == 'log4j-api' ) {
                    details.useVersion("2.17.0")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        if (project.hasProperty("buildEnv") && project.getProperties().get("buildEnv") == "github") {
            mavenCentral()
        } else {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        api "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.log4j"
        api "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.collections4"
        api "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonColleciton3Version}"
        implementation "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.mybatisGeneratorCore"
        implementation "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.itfswMybatisGeneratorPlugin"
        testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.4.0'
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$rootProject.ext.version.springCloudVersion"
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
    def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    compileJava {
        options.encoding = defaultEncoding
    }
    compileTestJava {
        options.encoding = defaultEncoding
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    /**
     * remove aliyun repo config from ~/.gradle/init.gradle into project
     * avoid to force other project in machine use aliyun
     * some international project could not fetch dependencies from aliyun
     */
    repositories {
        def PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL = 'https://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
                def url = repo.url.toString()
                if (url.startsWith('https://repo1.maven.org/maven2')) {
                    project.logger.lifecycle "Repository ${repo.url} replaced by $PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL."
                    remove repo
                }
            }
        }
        maven {
            url PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL
        }
        /****** Release Repo ********/
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ALIYUN_REPO_USERNAME")
                password System.getenv("ALIYUN_REPO_PASSWORD")
            }
            url 'https://packages.aliyun.com/maven/repository/2236707-release-REsSq7/'
        }
        /****** Snapshot Repo ********/
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME")
                password System.getenv("ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD")
            }
            url 'https://packages.aliyun.com/maven/repository/2236707-snapshot-lUlWG7/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `build.gradle(.kts)` file?

Comment: I have pasted my `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/experimental/spring-native/0.10.0/spring-native-0.10.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server:

I couldn't find a place in your `build.gradle` where you declare a spring repository to get `spring-native`. But the problem is there.

According to the error message (`401 - unauthorized`), you need to provide credentials for a spring repository just as you did for your company's repositories.

```
maven {
    credentials {
        username "<username>"
        password "<password>"
    }
    url "<spring repository url>"
}
```

Comment: is the spring.io need to password right now? I never typo any password to download spring dependencies for a long time.

Comment: Yes, it's weird, but the error said that... @Dolphin